# Android Image 64bit Encoded Image does not get Decoded in WCF

Tags: android, wcf, encoding, decoding

Hi um using both of these options one at a time to encode an image and send it over http post in android

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageData, Base64.URL_SAFE + Base64.NO_WRAP);
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(
                                    imageData,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

It's convert the image in to encoded string sends it over http post.

In WCF side um trying to decode the image as follows and the encoded image string comes as in encoded format.

```
   byte[] contents = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage.Trim());
```

After this it throws an exception saying

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.
```

what can possibly go wrong . I have a no clue of this. I will be thankful if anyone can guide me.